# What does the riot shield do?

Tags: counter-strike

In CounterStrike 1.6, there is a riot shield available on purchase on the CS team.
Unfortunately, even though I use it to block, I still get damage from the enemies guns.

What does exactly the shield protect you from?

Comment: Please use descriptive titles for your questions. "Counterstrike riotshield" isn't even a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does block bullets, so if you still get damaged, you probably don't use it correctly.

You should make sure that you are totally covered by it, so running and showing your back to an enemy would lead to shots in the back. Most probably. Also, don't forget that when you just use it, your legs(feet) are not covered by the shield, so enemies will probably shoot it. There are a few more things that you should keep in mind while using shield, but I do not remember them by heart anymore.

Comment: I tried it the other way around, I set the bots to only use shields and I use a sub machine gun and I can kill them despite the shield being properly used by the A.I.

Comment: @patcol "bots are stupid", try it with your friend

Comment: One important thing to remember when using the shield is don't use the riot shield.

Answer (score 0):

All bullets that hit the shield should do no damage to you.  If you are receiving damage, it may be that a part of you was showing.  Remember to right click to put the shield in front of you and also remember that enemies to the side or behind you will still hit you.

The riot shield is not supposed to block all damage at all times, so be sure to use it strategically.  It is probably best suited for blocking long range shots as you can more easily face directly at the shooter(s) and avoid them getting a good angle on you.

Answer (score 0):

It will block but you are always able to be hit, even head on there are part of you sticking out at least from the last time I played.

Shields are the reason why I stayed on 1.5 and never moved to 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Riot Shield help you to save yourself from the Bullets and by chance if your enemy is right behind you, you can of course injure him by hitting Riot Shield on him, It really works.

But the thing which you have to keep in mind that the enemy behind you can hit you from his bullet even if you had worn the Riot Shield. So you have to keep in mind to make yourself from all directions.